# lwjgl: How can I use glCallLists?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

So I have a bunch of addresses for my display lists. I can do those and get those on the screen with `GL11.glCallList(address)` easily enough. My problem is that I don't know how to use the potentially more efficient `GL11.glCallLists(something)` to call a bunch of lists with one native call. I've tried creating an IntBuffer with `IntBuffer ib = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(numberOfDisplayLists * 4).asIntBuffer()` and then `put(int index, int i)`ing the correct values into the IntBuffer, but when I call `GL11.glCallLists(ib)` nothing happens.

Help?

Comment: Why display lists?  Vertex arrays/buffers are probably at least as fast and actually supported in recent OpenGL revs.

Comment: Yeah... I'm rather of a newbie. Still, the question isn't really about display lists; it's about using ByteBuffers with lwjgl. That's what I need help with. And I'll need to use those no matter what I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it...

```
static int size = 10;
int compiledList;
IntBuffer lists;

lists = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(size);
compiledList = GL11.glGenLists(size);

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    GL11.glNewList(compiledList + i, GL11.GL_COMPILE);
    ...render here...
    GL11.glEndList();
    lists.put(offset);
}
lists.flip();

GL11.glListBase(compiledList);
GL11.glCallLists(lists);
```